# Convert PDF to HTML using pdfminer?

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, pdfplumber

I am working on a project to convert multiple PDF files into basic HTML to put onto a site. I want to extract the text and the font sizes from the PDF to parse directly into HTML tags.

I have tried using `pdfplumber` however I am having trouble getting the font sizes to match up with the text so I am wondering if there is a simple method using `pdfplumber` or if there is another library that can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdfminer.six (Python 3 compatible version of pdfminer)

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextContainer
```

I am having trouble with coming up a code that works on
a pdf on my pc that will also work on your pdf that I havent seen. I
will include code If I can take a look at your pdf

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me a KeyError, "LTTextContainer.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given"

Comment: Ok, I have edited it, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Now it extracts the text but not the font sizes

Comment: Can you try the edited version, if it doesnt work can I take a look at your pdf file? Can you send it to me if I give you my e-mail or something?